# Django migrations old database, forgot one model before

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-migration

I have existing database/production system pre-migration support for Django. We did start to use Djangos migration 2 years back it turns out I did forget to install migrations for one model that now causes problems.

2 years back I had the following models; Location, Tool and a third Log that points to instances of Location and Tool.

The 0001_inital.py for Log model has a dependency to Tool for 0001_inital but for Locations it points to _ *first* _

Now, today I am trying to get Location to use migration (so I later can add things to it, needed now) for the first time...

Running makemigration Location works and generates a new clean migration directory and all, but then when doing migrate --fake I get the following  django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration log.0001_initial is applied before its dependency locations.0001_initial on database 'default'.

Understand this is caused by the mistake earlier by forgetting to get migrations done for Locations when we started to use this in Django - any ideas how to resolve this in a good way?

Comment: Try fixing it with fake migration: `python manage.py migrate --fake appname migration_name`. Read [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps) on this to see if this is a viable option in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it - here is how it went.

1) reset the migration history for Log

```
>> python manage.py migrate --fake log zero
```

2) create first migrations for Location (this is what we forgot 2 years back)

```
>> python manage.py makemigrations locations
```

3) Edited the 0001_initial.py for Log and changed reference in it dependencies for Location from'_ *first* _' to '0001_initial'

4) clear (if any) migrations for locations

```
>> python manage.py migrate --fake locations zero
```

5) recreate projects all migration history

```
>> python manage.py showmigrations
>> python manage.py migrate --fake
```

6) Done - tested it by trying run migration to see if thing wirk

```
>> python manage.py migrate
No migrations to apply
```

:-)

Comment: I got this with your idea.
`InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration student.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.`